# Kinect for Xbox One (+ adapter) and Windows 10

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, kinect

Can I use Kinect Xbox One (with adapter like Kinect for Windows V2 device), SDK 2.0, to build applications on Windows 10? I've read the requirements for Kinect and it lists only Win 8.0 and Win 8.1.

I'd like to use Kinect Xbox One device with Unity 3D and Hololens. Before I buy the device I'd appreciate if anyone can share some experiance or at least to confirm that would be possible to develop apps with Kinect for Xbox One on Win10?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question may be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for replay. I'll ask there too and will constantly monitor both forums. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Kinect and UWP: new options in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kinectforwindows/2016/05/13/kinect-and-uwp-new-options-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/)